# MPEG-DASH playback on VLC

Tags: git, vlc, mpeg, mpeg-dash

I see that VLC should support MPEG-DASH playback from version 2.1 onwards, but I can't seem to get it to play back any DASH content, for either sample media found online or videos I've encoded myself. I've successfully tested these video manifests in a browser-based player, but I need to stream the video and collect bandwidth data from a computer that has no display.

When I try to stream a manifest from command line, it looks like vlc tries to parse the manifest using lua filters (because the file is coming over http, I presume), but I don't see any mention of DASH anywhere, and vlc fails to play the file. I don't have my test rig set up, but I can get a detailed output if anyone would like it.

Searching for a solution brought me [here](http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?p=351), but when I look through the vlc source from version 2.1.0 (with `git checkout tags/2.1.0-git` after cloning), the lines they mention to change are not in the files they mention. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this problem has been getting in the way of my research for more than a week now.

Answer (score 4):

VLC official version 2.2.1 does not support MPEG-Dash.

I have used nightly build 3.0 and it has dash support.

you can download it from here:

http://nightlies.videolan.org/.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried VLC nightly build vlc-3.0.0-git-20151220-0402-win64.7z release, it was able to playback mpd test files I have in use(*). Previous 3.x releases did not play anything. This version is not perfect picture as it flashes once in a while when downloading new segments.

http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win64/last/

(*) mp4(h264,aac) file dashed using a live profile.